# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to find the difference between 2 dates in whole months, I found a little script on Stack Exchange, but it keeps giving me an error of "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

I get this in chrome, it is a fairly simple HTML page.

It doesn't seem to like the first line of the function (var monthsLeft = to.getMonth() etc...)

(slightly simplified version for clarity:)

```
<script>
function monthDiff(from, to) {
    var monthsLeft = to.getMonth() - from.getMonth() + (12 * (to.getFullYear() - from.getFullYear()));
    if(to.getDate() < from.getDate()) {
        monthsLeft--;
    }
    return monthsLeft;
  }


function lumpChange() {

        var today = new Date();
        var april5th = new Date();
        var MonthsLeft = 0;

        today = '10/05/2015';
        april5th = '04/05/2015';
        MonthsLeft = monthDiff(today, april5th);  
  }

</script>
```

Comment: You've passed two strings to `monthDiff()`, where it looks to expect Date objects.

Comment: @George, sorry i over-simplified a bit too much there, edited to include var declerations

Comment: Ahh yes, sorted, i didnt realise what i was doing was re-dimensioning the date var's to strings, Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `monthDiff()` function looks as though it expects `Date` objects to be passed as parameters (it uses methods like `.getMonth()` etc). You are passing strings.

You don't modify `Date` objects by assigning strings to the variable the object was originally in.

You can define the `Date` when instantiating it:

```
function lumpChange(){
    var today = new Date(2015, 10, 05),
        april5th = new Date(2015, 04, 05);

    MonthsLeft = monthDiff(today, april5th); // -6
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljd4jwkv/)

If you need to set the date/time of a `Date` object after instantiating it, you can use the [setter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Setter).

**Documentation:**

- [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)